# Impossible to find following kanji

Tags: meaning, kanji, readings

[image]

I am trying to find the meaning and pronunciation of this kanji, but this kanji appears impossible to find.

Comment: What methods did you try?

Comment: If it exists, it can't be impossible to find — you just haven't looked in the right place...

Comment: @Earthliŋ [sorry, I couldn't help it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAzm4cVOIsw)

Comment: @jarmanso7 Haha, thanks for that! Reading my comment now 4 years later, it seems I'm also learning something about [myself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics))

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how the link you referenced relates to the conversation. Perhaps you meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_education))?

Comment: [I've found it in my favorite online dictionary](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjin/6516.html)

Answer (score 1):

学研 新漢和大辞典 lists this character as a variant of 灩. I reproduce parts of the entry here

> ## 灩
>
> ［異体］ 灔, [non-unicode character], 灎
>
> ［音］ エン（エム）（呉）（漢）
>
> ［意味］ ①《動》**ただよう** (ただよふ)。水がゆだかにたゆたう。②「灔澦堆【エンヨタイ】」とは、四川【シセン】省奉節県の西南、長江の瞿唐峡【クトウキョウ】の口にそそりたつ大岩石。付近は水流が急で、船の難所とされる。
>
> ［解字］会意兼形声。「水＋<sup>音符</sup>豔【エン】（＝艶。ゆたか）」。
>
> 【灩灩】エンエン（エムエム）①水がなみなみと満ちあふれるさま。②月光が水にただよって光るさま。

Comment: **［解字］会意兼形声。「水＋音符豔エン（＝艶。ゆたか）」。** is misleading. (1)「艶」does not have a reading of「ゆたか」, that refers to its left hand component「豊」only. (2) The「会意」classification only applies to definitions like「②月光が水にただよって光るさま。」, because「艶」means「つや」or「なまめかしい」, not 「ゆたか」. It's incorrect to say「会意兼形声」as the two classifications do not overlap in situations, just like you wouldn't say「象」, which can mean「かたち」, is「象形兼仮借」.

Comment: @droooze Thank you for your comment. The "category" 会意兼形声 seems to be a peculiarity of the 新大漢和辞典, used for 形声文字 whose "sound/voicing" component (here 豔) was chosen not at random, but rather for having a (possibly loose) connection with the character in question. I don't think that the dictionary claimed that ゆたか be a valid reading for 艶 — rather that the choice of 豔 as 形声 component could be associated with the meaning of ゆたか (either because 豔 itself has this meaning or because one of its components — here 豊 — does; 豊 is not read エン, so 豔 might just have been considered a fitting substitute).

Comment: That is indeed confusing, because 会意兼形声 is a valid categorisation for characters like「源」, as the history behind this character is very well known. In this example,「原」is known (not just have a loose connection with) to be the original form of「源」.

Comment: @droooze Before saying anything (else) wrong, let me look up what they 会意兼形声 means to them.

Comment: I've provided a reference to 会意兼形声 if you're interested. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktfnJ.jpg.